# A particular Diophantine approximation of $\pi/2$.

Tags: limits, diophantine-approximation

Recently I was playing around with the sequence $$\frac{1}{n\sin(n)},\ n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

After some computations, I was led to the following question: let $p_n,q_n$ be two sequences of natural numbers such that $$\left|\frac{p_n}{q_n}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right|<\frac{1}{q_n^2}.$$

> Can we find a subsequence of $q_n$ composed only by even number? Or is it the case that $q_n$ is odd except for a finite number of indices $n$?

Any idea or reference is welcome.

Comment: There are "links" between $p_n,q_n$ and continued fractions, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued+fraction+pi%2F2